# What are the "lumps" in the A380 flight-deck?

Tags: cockpit, airbus-a380

In this photograph of the Airbus A830 flight-deck there are two large "lumps" sticking up and out from the centre console, next to the engine thrust levers and flight-computer keypads:

[image]

I think they're just meant to be wrist-support for when pressing the keypad keys, but it seems odd to single-out that part of the flight-controls in particular for wrist-support. The lumps also seem rather tall to be used comfortably for extended periods (and I assume that's what [the pull-out keyboards in the trays are for](http://static.progressivemediagroup.com/uploads/imagelibrary/nri/aerospace/features/dreamliner-a380-cockpits/A380-displays.jpg), so why bother having secondary keyboards down there in the first place?) - and it also hinders access to the 'inner' keys closer to the engine controls.

Comment: They are also great hand holds for getting into/out of the seat!!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They are a different design of computer mouse:

[image: computer mouse]

As far as I can tell, the front disk is a track pad and the model in your picture has the mouse buttons on the front instead of the sides:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the manufacturer's website or other current source?

Comment: I recently saw a video about the last flight of _Jürgen "J.R." Raps_ who was chief pilot (I don't know the proper term) at Lufthansa. He explained some of the equipement of an A380, one of which was the mouse. _"The first thing you see are the numerous screens and two “palm stones” that resemble ostrich eggs – which turn out to be computer mice especially designed for pilots. **They make it possible to move the cursor properly even when there is turbulence.**"_ (http://pilotseye.tv/en/route/a380-san-francisco-the-final-flights-of-jr-juergen-raps/)

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNnXxkTxHhM) Jürgen Raps explains the controls of an A380. Jump to [3:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNnXxkTxHhM#t=03m40s) to see the mouse in action.

Comment: The picture is from this company's website: https://www.thalesgroup.com/en

Comment: I wonder if I can get a mouse like this for my desktop computer!

Comment: How do the mice work? I can't tell from the photos if they're trackballs or capacitative trackpads - or something else.

Comment: I think they are trackpads in this case. However, I have been in a Pilatus PC-12 that had a trackball design.